# SSIS while upgrading SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2005, ssis

I want to upgrade SQL server from 2005 to 2012 (I'm thinking of in-place upgrade).
Today I have several SSIS packages that works with other servers.
The SQL version in those servers is mainly 2005.

My question is what happen to the SSIS when i'm upgrading?

Do i need to upgrade the SSIS as well?

Could the SSIS work without me upgrading it?

Are there any compatibility issues with the integration server? can 2012 work with 2005 (and the opposite - because replication have compatibility problems)

I'm not a big fan of the SSIS so my goal is to touch it as less as i can so it will keep on working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to migrate your 2005 packages to 2012 using Data Tools. Depending on the complexity of each one this task will be more or less complicated. Here some useful links that I have used in the past:

https://devinknightsql.com/2012/05/16/upgrading-packages-to-ssis-2012/

https://sqldusty.com/2012/03/19/upgrade-2008-ssis-packages-to-2012-like-a-boss/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/03/22/package-upgrade-wizard/

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are great information but I would advise highly against a SQL 2005 to SQL 2012 in-place upgrade.  Odds are the hardware that the server runs on is old and antiquated.  I would highly recommend that you do a side-by-side migration, get on a newer, more current OS and newer hardware.

With that said, having a side-by-side migration allows you to test *ahead of time*.  We are currently moving our last 2005 box to 2014 so we built the new server that we can test all the DTS/SSIS conversions on and get all the kinks worked out.

All those links are great and you should definitely use them, but nothing will get you in a better position to do this migration than having a test server that you can do all your package upgrades, conversion and testing on before you go to production with it.

Why 2012?  Why not just go to 2014 or 2016?

Comment: I thought that by in-place upgrading i will not be forced to upgrade the SSIS as well (sadly i was wrong).
I've cloned the server so that the cloned server will use as my test server.
The 2012 is a third party limitation.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a couple of useful resources

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667275.aspx

https://sqldusty.com/2012/03/19/upgrade-2008-ssis-packages-to-2012-like-a-boss/